# Dataframe turning NA value into NaN

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an xls file with countries and country codes in it. I'm using the below code to pull this in as a dataframe:

```
dfCC = pd.read_excel('country_codes.xls')
```

This is working fine for all countries except Namibia. The country code I am using for Namibia is NA however when I pull this into my dataframe, the code for Namibia is being changed to NaN.

I need this pulled through as NA as I do a df merge on this dataframe and another dataframe based on the country code column.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: in the pd.read_excel pass a parameter `keep_default_na=False` default is True, one downside is that it will not read the actual missing values as NaN but your work will be done I think

Comment: worked perfectlt @psn1997 thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an additional parameter
`dfCC = pd.read_excel('country_codes.xls', keep_default_na=False)`
This will prevent python dataframe from replacing any missing values with NaN. 
This should work in your case. 
[Read here to know more about parameters to pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to cast the column to a string after reading it:

`dfCC['Country'] = dfCC['Country'].astype(str)`

This forces everything to a string, so NA is interpretted as "NA" not `NaN`.

The difference between this and psn1997's answer is that, in the end, numeric columns with null values are still `NaN`, so you can address each column's `Nan` rows differently.